# product gallery extra slide error [fotorama__thumb fotorama__error]

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3, fotorama, fotorama-slider

there is showing extra div slide on the product detail page. this happened on some product gallery pages. I have use Magento version 2.4.3-p1

Please help me to fix what is wrong with the gallery page.

i have add screenshot : [img1](https://ibb.co/FHsgBbh) [img2](https://ibb.co/zHX5PLf)

[image]
[image]